# Create reversable JSON Schema from SQL Server DDL (table)

Tags: sql-server, jsonschema

`tl;dr;` Convert a SQL Server table's DDL into JSON Schema && the Schema into DDL.

Let's pretend you have a table's DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
      Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    , LastName NVARCHAR(50) NULL
    , [Full Name] AS CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) PERSISTED
    , City VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
    , State VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CO'
    , SpecialRank DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

I would like to transform this into a JSON Schema with sufficient information in the Schema to be able to reverse-engineer it back into the DDL. To say that one more time: with the DDL I can create the Schema. With the Schema I can create the DDL.

Maybe there is a tool for this, that would be neat. I doubt it. But the heart of my question is based on my ignorance of the JSON Schema mechanics: is it possible and if so where in the schema can I store custom metadata on properties and objects that might enable this reverse?

Comment: Well, if everything fails, you can just use select *, (select * from sys.columns sc where sc.object_id = o.object_id for json path('columns')), (select * from sys.indexes ...) from sys.objects o for json path

Comment: check out the system metadata tables and just build json until you're done, sql server tables are quite finicky, because they can have a lot of different stuff like defaults, foreign keys, indexes of various things etc.

Comment: What JSON result would you like? Are you specifically referring to this type of JSONschema https://json-schema.org/?

Comment: JSON Schema is generally far richer than SQL Server's types, though -- and of course it allows for nesting, which T-SQL tables do not. You can certainly devise a translation of your own that is 1-1, just don't expect to be able to handle every possible JSON schema and turn it into a table in such a way that it will only accept valid input. Having said that, there are tools that use just this; for example Singer.io's [tap-mssql](https://github.com/singer-io/tap-mssql). (Of course, that's written in Clojure so not necessarily very practical for your purposes, but it's the thought that counts.)